# What to do when a theme doesn't show up in the enabled or disabled themes?

Tags: theming

I am moving from one server to another a Drupal 7 site. I have Drupal set up on the new server and modules installed. However, I would like to enable a theme (shoppica, in particular). I have followed the instructions in placing the files in ./sites/all/themese/shoppica, however it does not show up in the list of themes. What other steps am I missing in order to get this theme to show up?

Comment: Can you show us the shoppica.info file contents (this file should be in the theme directory)

Comment: If you were to put your them in `./sites/all/themese/shoppica` it would not work. Hopefully it was just a typo when you wrote the question, but just in case, it would be `./sites/all/themes/shoppica`. If you don't manage to fix your problem, you can also take a screenshot of your directory structure to see if you're missing something there.

Comment: Not sure why the correct answer cannot be displayed, as I posted it a couple of days after the question and then it was deleted by a moderator. But the theme, shoppica, was an installed theme. My client did not make me aware of that fact.

Comment: @AnthonyPotts "This theme, shoppica, was part of a whole install package." is not an answer, as it doesn't explain why the theme was not listed in the page listing all the installed themes.

Answer (score 1):

I would double check that all the theme files crossed over. As long as there is a .info file in the theme folder, it should show up in your drupal site.